# R data.table custom function

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset, that I import into R as a data.table. One of the columns is a duration in minutes x (integer) and I want a new column that is 60-x if x is between 0 and 60 (inclusive) or 0 otherwise. I have done this, but inelegantly, I'd like to know the most R way of doing this.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = c(60, 5, 0, 61, 47, 75))


defecit <- function(x){
if(x>0 & x<60)
{
60-x
}
else{0}
}

dataset$y = unlist(sapply(dataset$x,defecit))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please put your code in your question even if it is not elegant. Read [mcve]

Comment: Will do, as soon as I have access to it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with

```
dt[, x1 := pmax(60-x, 0)]
dt
#    x x1
#1: 60  0
#2:  5 55
#3:  0 60
#4: 61  0
#5: 47 13
#6: 75  0
```

If it includes negative numbers, then

```
dt[, x1 := 60 - x][x > 60 | x < 0, x1 := 0][]
```

Or as @Frank mentioned in the comments

```
dt[, y := (60-x)*between(x,0,60)][]
```

#### data

```
dt <- data.table(x = c(60, 5, 0, 61, 47, 75))
```

Comment: Ok, I'm still fairly noobish. What do the extra brackets do in the negative numbers example?

Comment: Another way might be `dt[, y := (60-x)*between(x,0,60)][]`. @user8041052 Brackets on the end print the result. Without them, you won't see the result of `:=` printed to console. See the package vignettes.